# UISwitch in UITableViewCell using Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiswitch

I've been trying to get a UISwitch shown as an accessory view in my UITableViewCell, but it just won't show up. I think there might be something I'm overseeing.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("enabledCell") as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "enabledCell")
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text = "Alarm enabled"

    var enabledSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero) as UISwitch
    enabledSwitch.on = true
    cell!.accessoryView = enabledSwitch

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Does this still happen if you change `Value1` to `Default`? I can't remember if that cell style hides the accessory view.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes, it does.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it's not in the code you posted. I just copy and pasted your code into a project and the switch shows up fine.

Comment: @AaronBrager this is what I see. http://i.imgur.com/eUTncRr.png. I properly linked the datasource and delegate :(

Comment: [Here's what I see](https://imgur.com/o3dWPnB). All I did was paste your code into Xcode's Master/Detail template app. Try moving more and more code over into that template app until your issue reproduces there.

Comment: @AaronBrager I tried that and there's still the same problem. I'm using the tableView in a normal ViewController, is there something I need to do instead?